# Show whether a module has or not at least 1 baseline

Tags: module, ibm-doors, baseline

I have a folder with a bunch of formal modules and I want to know which ones have at least 1 baseline. I started trying something like this:

```
Item icurr
Folder scr = current Folder
Baseline b = baseline(1, 0, null)

for icurr in scr do
{
   if( baselineExists(icurr, b) )
   {
      print name(icurr)
   }
}
```

The problem with this code is that baselineExists() only accepts a Module object as first parameter and when I declare icurr to Module instead of Item the for loop this does not recognize any module.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it easiest to use the `for baseline in module` loop.
Loop through all your items, either with using `for item in folder` (Items in sub-folders are not included, you will need a recursive function that loops through all found folders) or using `for item in project` (which will automatically traverse recursively all contained folders and projects).
For every item, check if it is a (formal) module using `if 'Formal' == type i then {}`. If so, get a module variable from the item. Usually, I do this using `Module m = read (fullName i, false, true); if !null m then...`.
Then, when you have opened the module, use code like

```
Baseline b = null
for b in m do {break} // stop loop at first found baseline
if (!null b) { 
   print "found a baseline in module " fullName(m) ": " major(b) "." minor(b)  " ("suffix(b)")\n"
}
```

Don't forget to close each module after the evaluation or the script will use a lot of memory